# NPE when finding PSNR value of RGB images

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, catalano-framework

I am trying to find MSE and PSNR of RGB images using [Catalano-Framework](https://github.com/DiegoCatalano/Catalano-Framework) 1.6.1

But I'm getting a `NullPointerException`

Here is my code:

```
// Code to Find PSNR
BufferedImage OrignalImage = null;
BufferedImage StegoImage = null;
File FileNameOrignal = null; 
File FileNameStego = null;

FileNameOrignal = new File("D:\\aexper\\test\\png\\linapng.png"); 
OrignalImage = ImageIO.read(FileNameOrignal);

FileNameStego = new File("D:\\aexper\\test\\png\\linapngSTEGO.png"); 
StegoImage = ImageIO.read(FileNameOrignal);

FastBitmap original = new FastBitmap(OrignalImage);
FastBitmap reconstructed = new FastBitmap(StegoImage);
ObjectiveFidelity o;
o = new ObjectiveFidelity(original, reconstructed);
//Error total
int error = o.getTotalError();
//Mean Square Error
double mse = o.getMSE();
//Signal Noise Ratio
double snr = o.getSNR();
//Peak Signal Noise Ratio
double psnr = o.getPSNR();
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Catalano.Imaging.FastBitmap.getGray(FastBitmap.java:1070) 
    at Catalano.Imaging.Tools.ObjectiveFidelity.getTotalError(ObjectiveFidelity.java:93) 
    at findpsnrimage.FindPsnrImage.main(FindPsnrImage.java:46) C:\Users\Ishita\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- snippets\run.xml:53: 

Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: During its execution it above program displays:                                      run:
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Catalano.Imaging.FastBitmap.getGray(FastBitmap.java:1070)
 at 

  Catalano.Imaging.Tools.ObjectiveFidelity.getTotalError(ObjectiveFidelity.java:93)
 at findpsnrimage.FindPsnrImage.main(FindPsnrImage.java:46)
     C:\Users\Ishita\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- 
     snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
     BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question. In particular: I reformatted the code, changed tags and moved the exception stacktrace to the question itself. Also I've reworded the question a little bit to state the exact problem you're facing. Hope this will help. Good luck